# Logic for adding OLI

Tags: apex, opportunity-lineitem, pricebookentry

I have the following code for adding a OLI to an Opp.
It is passed an Opp ID and will grab a few Pricebook Entires based on the already set Pricebook and the Product i have set.
It will then only add the Price Book Entry as an OLI if the currency matches that of the Opp. which needs to be done as the SELECT beforehand pulls the entry in three currency's. This all works perfectly.

```
Public class AutoCreateProduct {
    @InvocableMethod
    public static void ProductAssign(List<Id> OppIds) {

        Set<Id> pbIdSet = new Set<Id>();
        List<Opportunity> oppList = [Select Id, PriceBook2Id, CurrencyIsoCode from Opportunity where Id IN: OppIds];
        for(Opportunity opp: oppList) {
            if(opp.PriceBook2Id != null)
                pbIdSet.add(opp.PriceBook2Id);
        }

        if(!pbIdSet.isEmpty()) {
            List<OpportunityLineItem> oliList = new List<OpportunityLineItem>();
            List<PriceBookEntry> pbeList = [SELECT Id, PriceBook2Id, Product2Id, CurrencyIsoCode, Product2.Id, Product2.Name FROM PriceBookEntry WHERE Product2Id='01ta0000003vqHeAAI' AND PriceBook2Id IN: pbIdSet AND PriceBook2.isActive=true];
            for(Opportunity opp: oppList) {
                for(PriceBookEntry pbe: pbeList) {
                    if(opp.PriceBook2Id == pbe.PriceBook2Id && opp.CurrencyIsoCode == pbe.CurrencyIsoCode) {
                                           OpportunityLineItem oli = new OpportunityLineItem(OpportunityId= opp.Id, PricebookEntryId = pbe.Id, Quantity = 1);
                       oliList.add(oli);
                       break;
                    }
                }
            }

            if(!oliList.isEmpty())
                insert oliList;
        }
   }
}
```

I need to have this code add a Price Book Entry as an OLI based off some custom fields in the Opp.
my first attempt is as follows but iv messed it up somewhere (probably in a few areas) and it only works if the first IF is correct.

```
Public class AutoCreateProduct 
{
    @InvocableMethod
    public static void ProductAssign(List<Id> OppIds) 
  {

        Set<Id> pbIdSet = new Set<Id>();
        List<Opportunity> oppList = [Select Id, PriceBook2Id, CurrencyIsoCode, product__c from Opportunity where Id IN: OppIds];
        for(Opportunity opp: oppList) 
    {
            if(opp.PriceBook2Id != null)
                pbIdSet.add(opp.PriceBook2Id);
    }
        if(!pbIdSet.isEmpty()) 
      {
            List<OpportunityLineItem> oliList = new List<OpportunityLineItem>();
            List<PriceBookEntry> pbeList = [SELECT Id, PriceBook2Id, Product2Id, CurrencyIsoCode, Product2.Id, Product2.Name FROM PriceBookEntry WHERE PriceBook2Id IN: pbIdSet AND PriceBook2.isActive=true];

        for(Opportunity opp: oppList) 
        {
         for(PriceBookEntry pbe: pbeList) 
          {
           if (opp.product__c == 'Full')
            {
             if(pbe.Product2Id=='01ta0000003vqHeAAI' && opp.CurrencyIsoCode == pbe.CurrencyIsoCode) 
                {
                 OpportunityLineItem oli = new OpportunityLineItem(OpportunityId= opp.Id, PricebookEntryId = pbe.Id, Quantity = 1);
                 oliList.add(oli);
                 break;
                }
              {
               if (opp.product__c == 'Limited')
                    {
                     if(pbe.Product2Id=='01t30000002pvMa' && opp.CurrencyIsoCode == pbe.CurrencyIsoCode) 
                      {
                       OpportunityLineItem oli = new OpportunityLineItem(OpportunityId= opp.Id, PricebookEntryId = pbe.Id, Quantity = 1);
                       oliList.add(oli);
                       break;
                      }
            }
                  }


            }
          }
        }

            if(!oliList.isEmpty())
                insert oliList;
      }
  }
}
```

its going to be quite a long list of IF's as i have around 15 different custom fields that will each link to a whether a single PBE is added.I will also seemingly always need the check for if the currency matches aswell.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Regards

Comment: 15 diff custom fields in Opportunity or 15 different values of Opportunity.Product__c?